# Using tf.keras.utils.plot_model() in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I need to visualize the input/output dimensions of a Deep Learning model for debugging purposes. I have experience in Keras functional API and used `keras.utils.plot_model()` before which is helpful.

Now I am trying to move to Tensorflow 2.0 - primarily because of the more modular model definition etc. (hello pytorch!). But not sure how to use `tf.keras.utils.plot_model()` in this architecture. Below code -

```
class Encoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, enc_units, batch_sz):
    super(Encoder, self).__init__()
    ...

  def call(self, x, hidden):
    ...

class Decoder(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, dec_units, batch_sz):
    super(Decoder, self).__init__()
    ...

  def call(self, x, hidden, enc_output):
    ...
```

Now while training the model, checkpoints are saved

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()
    enc_hidden = encoder.initialize_hidden_state()
    total_loss = 0

    for (batch, (inp, targ)) in enumerate(dataset.take(steps_per_epoch)):
        batch_loss = train_step(inp, targ, enc_hidden)
        total_loss += batch_loss

    if batch % 100 == 0:
        print('Epoch {} Batch {} Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1,
                                                   batch,
                                                   batch_loss.numpy()))
    # saving (checkpoint) the model 
    checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)

    print('Epoch {} Loss {:.4f}'.format(epoch + 1,
                                      total_loss / steps_per_epoch))
    print('Time taken for 1 epoch {} sec\n'.format(time.time() - start))
```

I understand that this checkpoint has model information. But I am not sure how to get [similar visualization](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) like `tf.keras.utils.plot_model()` from this checkpoint.

Please suggest.

**EDIT**

This is how I define the checkpoint

```
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt")
checkpoint = tf.train.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer,
                                 encoder=encoder,
                                 decoder=decoder)
```

And then save checkpoint as shown in the original training code as

```
checkpoint.save(file_prefix = checkpoint_prefix)
```

Comment: You can load one of your checkpoints with [`tf.keras.models.load_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) and then pass that loaded model to [`tf.keras.utils.plot_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model).

Comment: @jakub can you give an example? I tried to do `model = tf.keras.models.load_model(MY_CHECKPOINT_PATH)` and it throws error `OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: MY_CHECKPOINT_PATH/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}` . So it seems I need to have either `.pb` or `.pbtxt` file to use `load_model`

Comment: Can you please give a more full example? Please show where you define `checkpoint`, and please show the directory tree (e.g., with the `tree` on unix-like systems) of the checkpoint directory.

Comment: @jakub please see the edit

Comment: @nad Is your problem solved? I'm also dealing with similar kind of problem. Also, is it necessary to use checkpoints for visualization?

Comment: @jakub Can you please post you comment as answer with the full code?

Comment: @nad just to visualize, why did you think it's necessary to load the checkpoint? The way we visualize in old `keras` is the same as new `keras`.

Comment: @Lawhatre It's not necessary to use checkpoint for visualization.